# MySql delete in trigger when value is null or not null

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

please how can i make in trigger something like this but without IF?? is it possible??

```
...
IF NEW.value IS NULL THEN
       DELETE FROM table WHERE column IS NULL;
ELSE
       DELETE FROM table WHERE column=NEW.value;
END IF;
```

practice when is value null so delete rows where column is null and when value is set so delete rows with column=value
i want this in trigger without IF

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a single statement :

```
...
DELETE FROM table WHERE column IS NULL OR column=NEW.value;
...
```

**edit:**

`DELETE FROM table WHERE (NEW.value IS NULL AND column IS NULL) OR (NEW.value IS NOT NULL AND column = NEW.value)`

Comment: wrong..it is not...i didnt test before... i want if any value so record with null stay in table

Comment: so you want to delete where column holds the new value? check the edit.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be functionnaly equivalent to you if/else:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE (NEW.value IS NULL AND column IS NULL) OR (column=NEW.value)
```